# Why is $a^n * a^m = a^{n+m}$, $a^n * b^n = (a*b)^n$ and NOT $a^n * b^m = (a*b)^{n+m}$???

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is $a^n \times a^m = a^{n+m}$, and $a^n \times b^n = (a\times b)^n$; but NOT $a^n \times b^m = (a\times b)^{n+m}$?

I know the properties, but I still cannot be convinced! If the first two are true, why isn't the last one? In other words, why doesn't applying two correct steps at the same time provide a correct unique step?

Comment: I'm very confused, why is $a^n a^m = b^{n+m}$?

Comment: Assuming that is meant to be an $a$ How about expanding the RHS of the one you're confused about? $(ab)^{n+m} = a^{n+m} b^{n+m} = a^n b ^m$ only if $n = m= 0$.

Comment: The first one says "when you multiply numbers with the same base you add the exponents". The second one says "when you multiply numbers with the same exponent you multiply the bases". The last one has neither the same exponent nor the same base. You can get an analogous property by forcing it to have the same base by writing $b=a^{\log_a(b)}$ so $a^n b^m = a^n a^{m \log_a(b)} = a^{n + m \log_a(b)}$.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ real numbers?  Is $*$ multiplication?  That's common in programming but rare in mathematics.

Comment: Just take $b=1$

Comment: I know, I use them correctly all the time, but it feels so WRONG that either the base or the exponent has to be the same, doesn't matter which one but one has to be

Comment: You can try $2^2\cdot 2^2 = 4^4$ ??? and see something wrong.  In fact $2^2\cdot 2^2 = 2^4$ from your first rule, and $2^2\cdot 2^2 = 4^2$ from your second rule.  But of course $4^4$ is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

Do not focus on algebraic manipulation for a moment, but focus on the definition of power:

$$a^n=a \times a\times \ldots \times a\text{; for n times of }a$$

And you'll figure out why.

Comment: Wow! This really helps! I can sum up the number of times if I have the same base, or I can make n groups of (ab)! If I don't have either, I can do nothing! Thank you!

Comment: @erohero yep, you get it!

Answer (score 0):

$$ a^n :=  \underbrace{ a \times a \times a   \times... \times a} \\ n $$

and :$$ a^m :=  \underbrace{ a \times a \times a   \times... \times a} \\ m $$

thus :

$$a^m \times a^n := \underbrace{ (a \times a \times... \times a)\times(a \times a \times... \times a)} =a^{n+m}\\ n+m$$

Now :

$$ a^n :=  \underbrace{ a \times a \times a   \times... \times a} \\ n $$

$$ b^n :=  \underbrace{ b \times b \times b   \times... \times b} \\ n $$

thus :

$$a^n \times b^n := \underbrace{ (ab \times ab \times ab \times...    \times ab)} =(ab)^{n}\\ n+m$$

Answer (score 0):

For exploration purposes, let's see what rule we might get from the first two rules.  If $n\geq m$ (just to avoid negative exponents),
$$a^nb^m=a^{n-m}a^mb^m=a^{n-m}(ab)^m$$

(Be careful with what you mean by "two correct steps at the same time."  It's a reasonable conjecture that it might be the case that $a^nb^m=(ab)^{n+m}$, but this is certainly not what you get by doing both rules "at once."  The only rules you can apply at once are ones which can be performed in either order, for instance two additions in $(1+2)+(3+4)=3+7$, but in your case not only can you not perform the rules in either order to $a^nb^m$, but neither rule actually applies.)

Comment: now I can see this too, thx